# Fuzzywuzzy Match with Python Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to compare two dictionaries, find matches, and push the keys from one dictionary, assuming the match ratio is >= 55, to a list.

For example,

```
foods = {
    "burger": {
        "flavor": ["savory"],
        "vegetarian" : "no",  
        "taste" : ["salty", 'umami'],
    },
    "padthai": {
        "flavor": ["savory", 'nutty'],
        "vegetarian" : "yes",
        "taste" : "salty",
    },
    "cake": {   
        "flavor": "sweet",
        "vegetarian" : "yes",
        "taste" : "tropical",    
    }
}
 
#Define user preference
userPref = {
        "flavor": ["savory","sweet"],
        "vegetarian" : "yes",
        "taste" : ["salty", "tropical"]
}

#Output desired: [cake, ratio score, pad thai, ratio score].
```

I am using fuzzywuzzy for the score ratio, but am getting this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

I've tried the following ways (with help from other forums), but keep getting this error:

Attempt 1:

```
def scoreMatch(foods, custDic):
    minMatch = 55
    matchLst = []
    for ele in foods:
        for key, value in ele.items():
            get_value(key, value)
            if(fuzz.token_set_ratio(custDic, value) >= minMatch):
                matchD = {}
                matchD[key] = value
                matchLst.append(matchD)
    print(matchLst)
```

Attempt 2:

```
matchLst= [d for d in foods if fuzz.token_set_ratio(userPref, list(d.values())[0]) >= minMatch]
```

Any help would be huge.

Thank you

Comment: The expression `[d for d in foods...]` results in a list of strings (the keys from the `foods` dictionary). You're trying to call `d.values()`, but `d` is a string, which has no `values()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your list comprehension the variable `d` is the key, which is of type `str` and has no attribute `values`. Try `foods[d].values()` instead, i.e.

```
matchLst= [d for d in foods if fuzz.token_set_ratio(userPref, list(foods[d].values())[0]) >= minMatch]
```

Comment: Thanks, @BernieD. Quick question, I noticed at score >=55, I get all three options. When I increase the score threshold to >=69, I get burger and cake, not pad thai and cake, which is the intended output.

I was thinking of doing a list comparison, but then I lose the score functionality. E.g.: return True if any(item in lst2 for item in lst1) else False

Thoughts?

Comment: I am not familiar with fuzzywuzzy. So I can only guess: It appears that you compare only based on the value of `"flavor"` because you take the 0th element of the list (`list(foods[d].values())[0]`). I don't think that is what you intended. But if it was, you should use the key explicitly and not convert to a list, which works only with Python3.6+ anyway.